# Conductor API has no attribute "xxxxxx"

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I have been trying to add a new table to the database. Now, I have created 
the table and I am going through conductor API to populate/update it. I have 
defined some function to achieve the task. There function are defined in conductor 
and db api, along with in conductor.manage and db.sqlalchemy.api. When I try 
to run the system it says

> AttributeError: 'ConductorAPI' object has no attribute 'xxxxxx'

while the function is properly defined in Conductor API as well as manager and 
db.API. I back traced the flow of the code and it looks like the code reaches till
conductor.api. The function at the conductor API is defined as:

> > """In class LocalAPI"""
> >     def xxxxxx(self, context, node_id, values):

```
     return self._manager.xxxxxx(context, node_id, values)
```

Now, after this it gives the error. Though the function is present in conductor.manager.
Please help me find out why am I getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured it out. You also need to add the interface to the conductor.rpcapi and now it's working fine!